# TO_DATE in QUERY with null year

Tags: sql, string, oracle, datetime, plsql

I want to do this in a single query where I check if my creation date is bigger then another but the table columns was divide out by year, month and day and sometimes there a illegal values in year.

```
Select count{*) from coverage cv
WHERE EXIST (Select * from addressTable ad 
and cv.date > to_date(ad.year||ad.month||ad.day, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

When I run this I get the error ORA-01841: Full year must be between -4713 and +9999 and not be 0.

Can I write something in the query to ignore the illegal values and just count the legal ones.

Comment: @eshirvana ISDATE() is not available in Oracle.  But a user-defined function could be used, as suggested at https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:890580198758.

Comment: And yet another example of why using correct data types is so important. The very fact that year, month, and day are separate columns instead of a single DATE column is, in and of itself, a _very_ serious design flaw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I write something in the query to ignore the illegal values and just count the legal ones?

If you are running Oracle 12.2 or higher, you can use `on conversion error`:

```
to_date(ad.year || ad.month || ad.day default null on conversion error, 'yyyymmdd')
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about this feature.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably single digits for month and day.  That can be fixed by interspersing hyphens:

```
to_date(ad.year || '-' || ad.month || '-' ad.day, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```